# dropbox keeps asking to login and link every reboot

Tags: linux, dropbox, hostname

It appears that on each reboot my dropbox forgets settings and wants to re-link the same device.

I installed dropbox.py, which in turn installed  ~/.dropbox-dist. I ran it successfully and "linked" it to my account; changed preferences e.g. proxy stettings etc. If I restart dropbox  it doesn't ask for password and remembers settings -- that's good.

However, after reboot, it considers itself on a new device, completely forgetting the linked account and preferences. I have to retype all that, be congratulated on successful linkage again, and when I check my account online I now have two (one more each reboot) devices that have the same name and same IP address.

Question: How do I tell dropbox that it's one and the same device and user, and make it remember the settings? Why doesn't dropboxd look into the folder .dropbox it created in my home directory with all that information? Does it use some sort of Host ID and what is it a function of?

Comment: Do you have you homedirectory mounted in a special way? Like on login or in a separate location that gets mounted later?

Comment: Thanks @madeddie. My home directory, which is also the directory where dropboxd in installed into, is on a USB drive. It also carries Porteus Linux and I boot from this USB drive. Porteus mounts and merges its modules and my user data at the start and presents a unified file system. Could that be a bad scenario for dropbox preventing it from accepting this system as one host?

Comment: I had a problem with my ~/.dropbox/ not being available when dropbox started. Found out because of http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111361&p=12515286#post12515286
Your problem might not be the same, but it sounds similar.